# Как автоматически добавлять "0" в случае неудачи?(Python, PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

В коде ТГ-бота есть следующий код:

```
#Любое число
        elif message.text.isdigit():
            date = datetime.now()
            link = f"https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/Расписание%20{message.text}.{date.month}.{date.year}.pdf"
```

Он при отправке юзером числа переделывает ссылку по формату `{сообщение юзера(число)}, {сегодняшний месяц}, {сегодняшний год}.`

Но есть небольшая проблема: если юзер, допустим, отправит просто 5, то ничего не произойдёт, нужно обязательно 05

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @MarianD, а чего тебе не хватает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно это прям при формировании строки сделать:

```
link = f"...%20{message.text:0>2}.{date.month}.{date.year}.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = message.text
...
elif text.isdigit() and len(text) <= 2:
  day = text if len(day) == 2 else "0" + text
  link = f"...{day}.{date.month}.{date.year}.pdf"
```

Comment: ну вот. опять код без пояснений.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а чего в нём пояснять? Просили добавить нолик - я добавил.

Comment: Впрочем, обнаружил, что можно сделать лучше.